# Showing a tensor is not a simple tensor

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $(e_1,e_2)$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Why can the element $e_1\otimes e_2 + e_2\otimes e_1$ in $ \mathbb{R}^2\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}^2 $ not be written as a simple tensor $v\otimes w$ for $v,w\in \mathbb{R}^2$?

If we suppose $e_1\otimes e_2 + e_2\otimes e_1=v\otimes w$, then can we conclude that $e_1=\lambda e_2$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$? This would give a contradiction since $e_1$ and $e_2$ are linearly independent. However, I am not sure if the argument is valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint** In this case we can (and it is instructive to) proceed naively:

If $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1$ is simple, there are $v, w \in \Bbb R^2$ such that $$e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1 = v \otimes w .$$ Writing $v = v^1 e_1 + v^2 e_2, w = w^1 e_1 + w^2 e_2$, substituting in the above equation, expanding, and comparing like coefficients gives a quadratic system. Show that it is inconsistent.

> The system is$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}0 &=& v^1 w^1 \\1 &=& v^1 w^2 \\1 &=& w^1 v^2 \\0 &=& v^2 w^2 \end{array} \right. .$$

**Hint for alternate solution** Show that, when regarded as bilinear forms on $(\Bbb R^2)^*$, $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1$ is nondegenerate but any simple tensor $v \otimes w$ is degenerate.

> The determinant of matrix representation of $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1$ with respect to the standard basis is $-1$, so it is nondegenerate. On the other hand, for any $\lambda \in \langle v\rangle^{\perp} \subset (\Bbb R^2)^*$, $(v \otimes w)(\lambda, \,\cdot\,) = \lambda(v) w = 0$, so $v \otimes w$ is degenerate.

Comment: Hi. Why can we compare the coefficients in the first method?

Comment: The coefficient comparison method works for any basis of any vector space: For a basis $(E_a)$, form the dual basis $(e^a)$ and write $v = \sum v^a E_a$ and $w = \sum w^a E_a$. Then, if $v = w$, $v^b = e^b(v) = e^b(w) = w^b$ (for any index $b$).

Comment: Thank you, but how do we know $\{e_1\otimes e_1, e_1\otimes e_2, e_2\otimes e_1, e_2\otimes e_2\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Any choice of bases $(E_a)$ of $V$ and $(F_b)$ of $W$ determines a basis $(E_a \otimes F_b)$ of $V \otimes W$. Our case is $V = W := \Bbb R^2$, $(E_a) = (F_b) := (e_a)$.