# Give an example that $u\in A\otimes_R B$ does not mean $u=a\otimes b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I'm working on the following problem:

> Give an example to show that for some ring $R$ and modules $A_R,_RB$, there exists some $u\in A\otimes_RB$ that $u\ne a\otimes b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

I know that the module $A\otimes_RB$ is generated by elements of the form $a\otimes b$, therefore $u$ is of the form $\sum_{i\in I}(a_i\otimes b_i)$. But how can I show there doesn't exist such $a\otimes b$ such that $\sum(a_i\otimes b_i)=a\otimes b$? Can anyone help me with an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the isomorphism $k[x]\otimes_k k[y]\cong k[x,y]$ will help you find such an element.

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314697/showing-a-tensor-is-not-a-simple-tensor